# SFLoginViewController not found in Cordova based Salesforce Hybrid apps?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, salesforce, hybrid-mobile-app

I am a little new to Salesforce Hybrid app.

Recently, I updated the Salesforce mobile SDK.

But, When running on IOS simulator, an additional Navigation bar for changing servers was added by the Salesforce Mobile SDK.

I want to remove that bar.

What I tried:

I tried the steps described in the following link

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/oauth_hide_gear_icon.htm

But, this gives me an error:

```
Receiver 'SFLoginViewController' for class message is a forward declaration
```

**Any Help is appretiated**

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property to hide navigation bar and settings button within "SFLoginViewController"

You need to write below code in `init` method in your main appDelegate.m file, you may have to add `init` the method if it is not there.

```
[[SFLoginViewController sharedInstance] setShowSettingsIcon:FALSE];
[[SFLoginViewController sharedInstance] setShowNavbar:NO];
```

Don't forget to import "SFLoginViewController.h" in appDelegate.m

But now as you have mentioned that "SFLoginViewController.h" is not available in your project, Simply you can create new file with name `SFLoginViewController` and add below code in that file:

```
/** The Salesforce login screen view.
 */
@interface SFLoginViewController : UIViewController

/** Returns a shared singleton of `SFLoginViewController` class.
 */
+(_Nonnull instancetype)sharedInstance;

/**
 * Outlet to the OAuth web view.
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong, nullable) IBOutlet UIView* oauthView;

/** Specify the font to use for navigation bar header text.*/
@property (nonatomic, strong, nullable) UIFont * navBarFont;

/** Specify the text color to use for navigation bar header text. */
@property (nonatomic, strong, nullable) UIColor * navBarTextColor;

/** Specify navigation bar color. This color will be used by the login view header.
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong, nullable) UIColor *navBarColor;

/** Specify visibility of nav bar. This property will be used to hide/show the nav bar*/
@property (nonatomic) BOOL showNavbar;

/** Specifiy the visibility of the settings icon. This property will be used to hide/show the settings icon*/
@property (nonatomic) BOOL showSettingsIcon;

/** Applies the view's style attributes to the given navigation bar.
 @param navigationBar The navigation bar that the style is applied to.
 */
- (void)styleNavigationBar:(nullable UINavigationBar *)navigationBar;
@end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I dont have a didFinishLaunch method in my AppDelegate.m file :(

Comment: I tried it but still not working although also not getting any errors :(. Any other suggesstions.

Comment: Ohh, then you should try by adding it in init function.